View minus sign as operator or part of the number? How to differentiate?
I came across this problem,looking at the distributive law "a*(b+c) = ab+ac" / "a*(b-c) = ab-ac".
Lets say we have the following term: -4 * (2 - 4)
What would you say is c? Is c -4 or is it 4?
We would either have:
(-4 * 2) + (-4 * -4) = -8 + 16 = 8
or:
(-4 * 2) - (-4 * 4) = -8 - (-16) = 8
in the latter case, i find it confusing, that c is 4 and not -4. I am confused on how to view the minus sign. Is it part of the number? Is it the operator? How do I distinguish these?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

If you get the same answer either way, then what difference does it make?

In the latter computation, $c$ most definitely is taken to be $4$ (and not $-4$) in the rule $a(b - c) = ab - ac$. I'm not really sure why you don't think so.

@GerryMyerson Because at first I had (-42) - (-4-4), which would be wrong. And now I fear making a similar mistake again in different formulas. Thats why I want to understand, how to deal with the minus sign the correct way.

The correct way is the way that yields the correct answer. Unless you have an example where one way produces an incorrect answer, you have no question.

You hit upon a relatively important topic here. The thing is that strictly speaking, the sign "$-$" denotes two different things.

As a unary operator, the sign is used to define the additive inverse of a number. In other words, for a number $a$, the number $-a$ is defined as the unique solution to the equation $a+x=0$.
As a binary operator, the sign is used as shorthand for adding the additive inverse of a number, i.e., the expression $a-b$ is shorthand for $a+(-b)$.


Now, to answer your question, $c$ can be either, depending on which rule you choose.
We start off with the expression $$-4\cdot (2-4)$$
If you choose to apply the rule $a\cdot (b+c)=ab+ac$ onto the expression, we need to find values of $a,b,c$ such that $$a\cdot(b+c)=-4\cdot (2-4).$$
Noting of course that, by definition, $2-4$ is simply $2+(-4)$, it's relatively easy to see that setting $a=-4, b=2$ and $c=-4$ allows us to apply this rule.

If we choose to apply the rule $a\cdot (b-c)=ab- ac$, then we need to set $a=-4, b-2$ and $c=4$.
So, both rules apply, with different values of $c$.

The binary operator can also be defined by $a-b$ being the value $d$ such that $b+d=a$ if such value exists and is unique. For natural numbers it doesn't always exist, resulting in a partial function/binary operator, but for integers it always exists and is unique.
